# Write a string in a CSV column

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm very new at Powershell scripting, hit the wall again. Need help please!

I have a powershell script that I use to do some operations on a CSV file. I need to add another operation to this script. I need to write a certain string to the column J

Here is the existing script

```
Import-Csv C:\sandbox\test.csv -Header A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z | 
    ForEach-Object {$_.Z = $_.U; $_} |
    Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty B | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Set-Content C:\sandbox\out.csv
```

Now, I want to add the word "text" to each of the rows, in column J.

Comment: `{$_.Z = $_.U; $_.j += 'text'; $_}`

Comment: worked well, thanks, I removed the '+' because I wanted to replace the existing content there. Thank you!

Comment: np, as you are already doing the exact same thing, i think you just didn't think about adding `;` and a new expression after that

Comment: @4c74356b41 Post an answer

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you insist. the easiest way to do that, would be to add another `;` and another bit of code to make j equal to 'text'

```
{$_.Z = $_.U; $_.j = 'text'; $_}
```

Answer (score 0):

other solution :

```
Import-Csv C:\sandbox\test.csv -Header A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z |
    select *, @{N='J';E={'TEST'}}, @{N='Z';E={$_.U}} -ExcludeProperty B, Z, J | 
        export-csv "C:\sandbox\out.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```